# nginx listen on specific interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, routing, reverse-proxy

I'm running a Nginx as a proxy server, forwarding to 10.12.96.4.

I would like the NGINX server to listen on `ens3:`, and forward requests through `tun0

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`:

```
server {
    listen 149.28.239.231:80;
    server_name default_server;

    location / {
       proxy_pass http://45.77.185.160:80;
       # proxy_pass http://10.12.96.4:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}

server {

    listen 443;
    server_name example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/cert.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;


    location /
    {
        proxy_pass https://45.77.185.160:443;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Here's my interface config

```
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
inet6 ::1/128 scope host
inet 100.68.26.219/10 brd 100.127.255.255 scope global ens3
inet 149.28.239.231/23 brd 149.28.239.255 scope global ens3:1
inet6 2001:19f0:5:65d3:5400:1ff:fea6:9b5/64 scope global
inet6 fe80::5400:1ff:fea6:9b5/64 scope link
inet 10.8.0.3/24 brd 10.8.0.255 scope global tun0
```

Comment: can you make the interface config neater? And/or add `ip route` neatly?

Comment: I'm unsure what the question is. You already know how to bind to IP addresses with the `listen` directive and how to proxy. Aren't you done?

Answer (score 6):

You can bind to the network address of the interface in question.

Based on your interface config, your listen config would look like:

`listen 149.28.238.0:80;`

I'm in the process of setting up an active/active HA cluster, and need this to work.  My test config is below.

```
[root@b7311458cb35 nginx_plus]# cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/docker-test.local.conf 
# MANAGED BY PUPPET
server {
  listen 172.17.0.0:80;

  server_name           docker-test.local;
  status_zone docker-test;


  index  index.html index.htm index.php;
  access_log            /var/log/nginx/docker-test.local.access.log combined;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/docker-test.local.error.log;

  location / {
    proxy_pass            http://docker-test;
    proxy_read_timeout    90s;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90s;
    proxy_send_timeout    90s;
    proxy_set_header      Host $host;
    proxy_set_header      X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header      X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header      Proxy "";
  }
}
```

My network details

```
[root@b7311458cb35 nginx_plus]# ip route
default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 
172.17.0.0/16 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.4
```

Testing the config:

```
[root@b7311458cb35 nginx_plus]# curl  http://172.17.0.4:80/ | head -5
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   612  100   612    0     0   101k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  119k
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
<style>
```

Comment: After reviewing my nginx configuration, I noticed that the default server was still listening on the 172.17.04 IP address, which allowed the curl to work.  I'm now following the setup on https://hexadix.com/ha-proxy-using-vip-keepalived/ for getting the floating IP address to work.

In regards to the outbound address, there is a proxy_bind attribute that can be used to specify an interface via IP address.

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/#choosing-an-outgoing-ip-address

Answer (score 2):

This has been answered. It's not possible to bind to an interface because nginx has no concept of layer2/3. Use static IPs, or wrapper scripts which monitor dynamic IPs, write new .confs and zero-downtime restart as needed.

https://stackoverflow.com/q/39536714/246672